# Rails 3.1 active_scaffold 'jQuery("form.as_form").live' is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activescaffold

Rails 3.1.10
Active_scaffold 3.2.17

I got the js error message:

```
Event thread: DOMContentLoaded
Uncaught exception: TypeError: 'jQuery("form.as_form").live' is not a function
Error thrown at line 25, column 5503 in <anonymous function>() in http://localhost/assets/application.js?body=1:
jQuery("form.as_form").live("ajax:beforeSend",function(e){var t=jQuery(this).closest("form");return....................................
```

Could anyaone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent half a day to find out what is wrong.

**jQuery("form.as_form").live' is not a function** it is because of I have in my gemfile:

gem 'active_scaffold'

It's installing a 3.2.17 version that contains obsolete for Jquery 1.9 calls .live in different js libraries). Instead there have to be .on call. But released version 3.2.17 of active_scaffold contains **.live** ((

At last My solution is

**gem 'active_scaffold', git: "https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold.git"**

it contains 3.3.0.rc and it contains .on jquery calls instead .live.

Answer (score 1):

Master branch on github of active_scaffold has dropped Rails 3.1 support, so the solution for that is to update your Gemfile to fix the jquery-rails gem to to one that uses JQuery 1.8.3:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.1.4'
```