# active_scaffold w/ Rails 3.2 gives no visible response for search, edit, new actions etc

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, prototypejs, activescaffold

I added a couple of models and controllers with active scaffold. However, whenever I click any of the actions such as new, edit, search, show etc. nothing is visible in the browser. It seems that the server is responding to it as the logs show:

```
Started GET "/organisms/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-15 12:55:35 -0400
Processing by OrganismsController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Organism Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "organisms".* FROM "organisms" WHERE "organisms"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "genes" WHERE "genes"."organism_id" = 1
  Rendered /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/active_scaffold-3.2.19/frontends/default/views/_show_columns.html.erb (2.9ms)
  Rendered /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/active_scaffold-3.2.19/frontends/default/views/_show.html.erb (15.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 32ms (Views: 26.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

But nothing changes in the browser window. The Firebug 'Net' logs show a response header:

```
 Cache-Control  max-age=0, private, must-revalidate Connection  close
 Content-Type   text/javascript; charset=utf-8
 Etag   "c08465bfa6a67a8fb4f88964513a6b23" Server   thin 1.5.0 codename
 Knife X-Request-Id 6ee347aa85988460733ffbda65ea12ee X-Runtime  0.036693
 X-UA-Compatible    IE=Edge
```

The response looks like html to me:

```
<h4></h4>

<dl>
  <dt>Name</dt>
    <dd class="name-view">
    - &nbsp;
  </dd>
  <dt>Genes</dt>
    <dd class="genes-view">
    - &nbsp;
  </dd>
</dl>

<p class="form-footer">
  <a href="/organisms" class="as_cancel" data-remote="true">Close</a>
  <img alt="loading indicator" class="loading-indicator" id="as_organisms-create-1-loading-indicator" src="/assets/active_scaffold/indicator.gif" style="visibility:hidden;" />
</p>
```

I suspect the problem two issues:

1. The response header mentions js, but the response body is HTML. Though that can happen for AJAX I think.
2. I am using jquery in my assets (application.js headers) while active_scaffold may be tryung to use prototype. How do I check this? Note that in Rails 3.2, one does not mention prototype or jquery while installing the active_scaffold gem : https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/Getting-Started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the data on the page changing?  I think `activescaffold` is using ajax to re-render portions of the page, so you will not see the hole page change.  If there is nothing different on the screen then it will look like nothing happened.

Answer: Use git master `gem 'active_scaffold', :git => 'git://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold.git'` see below for details

Comment: Nothing on the page changes. I understand that the whole page may not change but nothing changes.

Comment: So I may have not stated that correctly, but it looks like you are doing a `#show` on a `Organism` have any attributes of that `Organism` changed. You could go into `rails console` and add a new `Gene` to an existing `Organism`

Comment: I added some data from the console. It seems if I right-click on the edit, show, new links and select open in new tab I can see the sent forms but the page is not updating the response in the page. I think it could be the event handlers. But jquery and active_scaffold.js are included.

Comment: If you are using `Chrome` or `Safari` open up the developer console and see if you are getting javascript errors.

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: jQuery(...).live is not a function`!

Comment: Have a look at this then `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457641/rails-3-1-active-scaffold-jqueryform-as-form-live-is-not-a-function`

Comment: Thank you, git it! I just needed to use the edge version from git! You wanna add it to your answer? Thanks!